# Regular expression to make distinct capture groups within a repeating pattern of HTML tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'd like to make a capture groups with text between `<li>` and `</li>` every time those HTML tags appear.

For example:

`<li>packaged in a classy box</li> <li>measures 0.9x1.15" (2.3x2.8cm)</li> <li> <em>925 silver</em> and <em>14k white gold</em> arrive with an 20" <strong> silver chain </strong> </li>`

So the output I need is:

Capture Group 1: `packaged in a classy box`
Capture Group 2: `measures 0.9x1.15" (2.3x2.8cm)`
Capture Group 3: `<em>925 silver</em> and <em>14k white gold</em> arrive with an 20" <strong> silver chain </strong>`

I tried look arounds, but they match **everything** between the very first and very last `<li>` and `<\li>`.

Comment: "but they match everything between" take a look at lazy/reluctant quantifiers https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy. But generally regex and HTML is not good match. For instance if HTML is more complex and have nested lists like `<li>foo</li>  <li><ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul></li>` then regex like `<li>.*?</li>` will return `foo` but then will return `<ul><li>A` instead of full `<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>`. Generally HTML should be *parsed* and its elements should be *selected* from parsed DOM (for instance via CSS selector or xpath expression)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `.*?` pattern that means "Match a minimal number of any character".

For instance, suppose that your HTML input is saved in the file input.html. Here is a Perl program using a Perl regex that does the job:

```
cat input.html | perl -pe 's%<li>(.*?)</li>.*?<li>(.*?)</li>.*?<li>(.*?)</li>%capture group 1: \1\ncapture group 2: \2\ncapture group 3: \3\n%'
```

The output is:

```
capture group 1: packaged in a classy box
capture group 2: measures 0.9x1.15" (2.3x2.8cm)
capture group 3:  <em>925 silver</em> and <em>14k white gold</em> arrive with an 20" <strong> silver chain </strong>
```

Note that using some regex to parse HTML is not the best way to do things properly. A far better way would be to apply a [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) style sheet to your input using a XSLT processor like xsltproc, or use a DOM parser. A DOM parser may be the best tool since it may handle some malformed HTML input.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Appreciate the tip on parsing HTML. I have to use HTML unfortunately for this specific situation (I'm going to find a solution in the future).